# Side Navigation for HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a side navigation bar for a website.  However, I am running into a problem where the Font Awesome Icons are being pushed down below the link when it closes.  If I take them away, the navbar opens/closes over the links just fine.  The code is on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpbYGP)

Here is the HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
<section class="container-fluid">
    <section class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" onclick="openMenu()" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <brand class="navbar-brand">Menu</brand>
    </section>
</section>
```

```
<nav id="sideNav" class="sideNav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeMenu()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></a>
<a href="#">About<i class="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#">Projects</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
```

Here is the CSS for the side nav

```
.sideNav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: white;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideNav a , i{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
}


.sideNav .fa-times {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 25px;
font-size: 1.5em;
margin-left: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Is there something wrong in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
.sideNav a , i{
display: block;
}
```

is the problem.

It should be

```
.sideNav a
   {
     display:block;
   }

.sideNav a i{
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

edit:
The icon needs to be displayed as inline.

```
.sideNav a i {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[Link to Codepin](http://codepen.io/criticalthewizard/pen/KapBMR)